# why my find method in beautifulsoup return None when scraping coursera website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to **scrape** data analysis courses from Coursera website. when I inspect the course's name from the browser I see this value:

`<h2 class="cds-1 card-title css-iyr9nj cds-3">Google Data Analytics</h2>`

so I wrote this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.coursera.org/search?query=data%20analysis'
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
course = soup.find('h2' , class_ = 'cds-1 card-title css-iyr9nj cds-3')
print(course)
```

But unfortunately it retrieved None. any help?
thank you in advance

Comment: If you load that URL in your favourite browser and inspect the HTML, you will see that the classes cds-1 and css-iyr9nj are not there. It's possible that you will only see such classes after a successful login to that site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw `html` and find the course name in `span` with `class=product-name body-2-text` then write the below code.

you can try this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.coursera.org/search?query=data%20analysis'

html = requests.get(url).text

html

soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')

for course in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "product-name body-2-text"}):
    print(course)
```